# JavaScript call function after form submit complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden form created with a jquery plugin and I need to run a function after the submit has happened but it doesn't appear to be getting called.
I need to get the new csrf details after the form has been posted.

After submitting the form I want to get the newly generated csrf details

```
$(this).on('click', function() {
    $('#' + settings.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + '-export-csv').submit();
    get_csrf_details();
});
```

Html link with export-csv class and data which will be used in the plugin. Using smarty template.

```
<a href="#" class="export-csv" data-title='Landlords' data-data='{base64_encode($landlords_json)}'>
    Export (CSV)
</a>
```

ExportCSV plugin

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.exportCSV = function ( options ) {

        return $(this).each(function() {
            var settings = $.extend({
                title: null,
                data: null,
                link: '/',
            }, options);

            settings.title = $(this).data('title');
            settings.data = $(this).data('data');

            var hidden_form = "<form id='" + settings.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + "-export-csv' action='" + settings.link + "' method='POST' style='display: none;'>" +
                    "<input type='hidden' class='csrf_field' name='" + csrfName + "' value='" + csrfHash + "'>" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='title' value='" + settings.title + "'>" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='data' value='" + settings.data + "'>" +
                "</form>";
            $(this).append(hidden_form);

            $(this).on('click', function() {
                $('#' + settings.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + '-export-csv').submit();
                get_csrf_details();
            });
        });
    }
}(jQuery));

$(".export-csv").exportCSV({
    link: '/dashboard/export-csv'
});
```

// get the csrf details from server

```
var get_csrf_details = function get_csrf_details() {
    $.get('/ajax/get-csrf-details', function(response) {
        var csrfName = response.data.csrf.name;
        var csrfHash = response.data.csrf.hash;

        // const csrf_input1 = document.querySelector('.csrf_field');
        const csrf_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('csrf_field');

        for (i = 0; i < csrf_inputs.length; i++) {
            csrf_inputs[i].name = csrfName;
            csrf_inputs[i].value = csrfHash;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: There's no way to know when a submission from a `<form>` element has been successfully completed. Given what you're doing it would make much more sense to just use AJAX. This means you can control the exact logic executed when a response is received and saves having injecting a form and faking a submission,

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan True, good shout. I threw in a timeout but need to be sure on the time finishing.

Comment: A timeout is far from ideal too, as it will either mean that the user is waiting longer than required after the request completes, or if the request takes too long the timeout will execute before the page is ready and the logic will break completely. I added an answer for you below which shows how to do this in AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to know when a submission from a `<form>` element has been successfully completed.

However, given what you're doing it would make much more sense to just use AJAX. This means you can control the exact logic executed when a response is received and saves having to inject a hidden form and faking a submission, which is far from ideal. Try this:

```js
$.fn.exportCSV = function(options) {
  return $(this).each(function() {
    var settings = $.extend({
      title: null,
      data: null,
      link: '/',
    }, options);

    settings.title = $(this).data('title');
    settings.data = $(this).data('data');

    $(this).on('click', function() {
      var data = {
        title: settings.title,
        data: settings.data
      };
      data[csrfName] = csrfHash;

      $.ajax({
        url: settings.link,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
          // the submission has been made, perform required logic here. 
          get_csrf_details();
        },
        error: function() {
          // something went wrong, debug it!
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

A couple of things to note. Firstly, it may make more sense to return the new CSRF in the response of the first request. This will save your network traffic.

Secondly, you're *always* setting `settings.title` and `settings.data` to match the `data` attributes on the element this function was defined on, so using a `settings` object is pointless as it will always be overwritten, even if no `data` attributes are provided. You could instead amend the logic to only use the `data` if they exist.

Comment: It will eventually get moved to a method call but not today :(

Comment: This now isnt doing the download like it did previously with the form submit. Its going to PHP server code and debugging seems to show everything works as before. All except the download of the csv file. Do i need to catch the response now or something?